Getting ` warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous.` after `git clone --bare` and `git worktree add`
I'm lookng into git worktrees b/c I want to work on multiple branches at once. Did the following setup
# Created new E:\ partion
cd /d E:
mkdir repos
cd repos
git clone --bare <repository-url>/foo

# above creates the bare repo foo.git
cd foo.git
git worktree add master
cd master
dir # shows the foo repo's master branch's source code as expected

but the I do git status and get
warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous.
warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous.
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

Not sure what that means, but I try to create another worktree for a new branch
cd E:\repos\foo.git
git worktree add dev/bar

which prints
warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous.
Preparing worktree (new branch 'bar')
warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous.
fatal: ambiguous object name: 'HEAD'

Still in foo.git I do git dir which contains master and worktrees, but no dev nor dev/bar and I do dir worktree and it contains master, but also no dev nor dev/bar.
I used VS Code to search for bar in E:\repos\foo.git and got no results.

Someone know why I got warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous., and how to fix it?
Alternative, if I should be following a different set up for git worktree lmk!
Thanks!

Per jthill's comment I tried
cd E:\repos\foo.git
git ls-remote origin HEAD

which prints
123...        HEAD
246...        refs/heads/HEAD

I looked at the remote repo and commit ID 123... corresponds to a very recent commit (7/19), while commit ID 246... corresponds to a very old commit (years old).
Then I did
git config init.templatedir
cd master
git status

which prints
warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous.
warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous.
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

and git log which prints
warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous.
commit 987... (HEAD -> master)
...

and commit ID 987... corresponds to a commit from 7/17.
I also did git branch >> branches.txt and found that there is a branch named HEAD


How about starting with a clone that is not bare?

It's something about the repo you're cloning, or possibly you've got a misconfigured default template. in the bare clone, say git ls-remote origin HEAD and git config init.templatedir. Doing what you show here on a repo I had handy works fine.

If you're on a case-blind filesystem you could also have a branch named head.

The age of the commits is irrelevant. Remove the branch HEAD a.k.a refs/heads/HEAD from the remote repository. Its existence is unusual and most likely an error. You can remove it with git push --delete refs/heads/HEAD, for example. How a local branch named HEAD was created is unclear; your command sequence should not have done it.

Why use a bare repository? I keep seeing people who use a bare repository + worktrees and I don’t get where this practice comes from.

Using a bare clone is recommended in several git worktree how to YouTube videos, e.g. https://youtu.be/IK_mjDqGUYE?t=230.

@joseville "consider the source", generally a good rule to please always remember and never forget.

I deleted the foo.git and cloned it again. Immediately after cloning I did git worktree add master and still got
Preparing worktree (checking out 'master')
warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous.
warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous.
Updating files: 100% (N/N), done.
Filtering content: 100% (28/28), 3.09 MiB | 991.00 KiB/s, done.
warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous.
HEAD is now at ### Merged PR ##: ...

But now I know why. The foo repo has a branch named HEAD and unlike git clone <repository-url>/foo, git clone --bare <repository-url>/foo fetches all branches including HEAD. -- When I do git branch I get a lot of branches which isn't the case when I did git branch on my non-bare foo repo.

The solution: I deleted foo.git again. And did
cd E:\repos
git init --bare foo.git
cd foo.git
git remote add origin <reposiotry-url>/foo
git worktree add master
cd master
git fetch origin master
git branch --track master origin/master

